# Sorting an array by positive and negative numbers (double)

Tags: arrays, sorting, double

I am looking for a solution to sort an array by positive and negative double numbers:
for example `{2.0, -1.0, -5.0, 3.0, -9.0, 1.0}`
to `{2.0, 3.0, 1.0, -1.0, -5.0, -9.0}`

I found this code sample tried to customize it to work for double type numbers but without success.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     double num[] = {5.39, -3.44, -18.12, 1.22, 0.77, -6.8};

    for (int j = num.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (Integer.signum((int) num[i]) < Integer.signum((int) num[i+1])) {
                int temp = (int) num[i];
                num[i] = num[i+1];
                num[i+1] = temp;               
            } 
        }  
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
}
```

In this case it print out  `[5.39, 1.22, 0.77, -3.0, -18.0, -6.8]`

Why does it prints `-18.0` instead of `-18.12` and `-3.0` instead of `-3.4` but `-6.8` is printed correctly?

Comment: What did you expect to happen when cast a `double` to an `int` and back?

Comment: Are you sure that sorted array from your example is correct? It does not seem to be sorted in any order.

Comment: @Kamil I think the example preserves order from the input array, except for separating positive and negative. What happens to zero?

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan, I just assumed that the second array shows already sorted items that were provided by first one. But maybe my assumption was wrong :)

Comment: @Kamil Forgot to write it down that positive and negative numbers must maintain the same order like in the example.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Nevermind, that was suggested fix by IDE